# IsDlg=1 is not working for custom list web part item to show in dialog

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I have created custom list web part and using that web part in home page. when i click on item its not opening in dialog. I used below code.

Can anyone suggest me what is the problem ?

```
     SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                     query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'     Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
                            query.RowLimit = Convert.ToUInt16(RowLimit);
                            SPList list = web.Lists[ListName];
                            SPListItemCollection listItemsCollection = list.GetItems(query);
                            foreach (SPListItem listItem in listItemsCollection)
                            {
                                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                                TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();
                                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();

                                string docName = listItem.Title;
                                link.Text = docName;
                                try
                                {
                                   link.NavigateUrl = web.ParentWeb.Url  + list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "?id=" + listItem.ID + "&IsDlg=1";

                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    link.NavigateUrl = web.Url + list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "?id=" + listItem.ID ;
                                }

                                //link.Target = "_parent";
                                tableCell.Controls.Add(link);
                                tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
                                table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
                            }
                            this.Controls.Add(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are getting some exception, that's why its creating a the url with out parameter. Can you please debug it or tell me the url which you are getting on Home Page.

Thanks

Correct me please

Comment: Hi Ali Thanks for reply. This is the url http://testserver/Lists/Open%20Positions/DispForm.aspx?id=1

Comment: So its clear you are getting exception in getting in line link.NavigateUrl = web.ParentWeb.Url  + list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "?id=" + listItem.ID + "&IsDlg=1";

Comment: So you are getting URL with out IsDig=1. Please debug, probably there is some problem in getting web.parentweb.Url

Comment: Normally it works. thats why put break point here to check, is it getting context or weburl? After reading the exception you can read it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26150/discussion-between-janakiakula-and-ali-murtaza)